# how could I create a mean value column with the multiple values column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, number-formatting

I've created a new column with str.findall() method because the original value is a sentence, like "Preis ab 23,48 EUR pro Person/Tag" so I extracted the number ['23,48'] as a new value, but some sentences contain two prices, Like "from €83 to €120", so I will get the new value ['83' , '120'], now I want to replace the row with two values with the average, but I can't find a solution plan

The extract method is as follows:

```
df['pricerange_All'] = df.pricerange.str.findall(r'([0-9,.]+(?:\.[0-9,.]+)?)')
```

and the dataframe which looks like this:

```
       pricerange_All 
0         ['16.51']
1         ['17,61']
2         ['16,96']
3         ['13,70']
4         ['17,85']
.
100       ['690.94', '690.76']
```

as you can see some of the values have two prices

I've try the solution :

```
df2= pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in df.pricerange_All])
df2.columns = ['price_{}'.format(x+1) for x in df2.columns]
```

but it didn't work

How to separate the column or create a new column that save the mean value of each row?
like:

```
         mean_price    
0         16.51 
1         17,61 
2         16,96   
3         13,70   
4         17,85  
.           .
100       690.85
```

I've racked my brains and really need to solve this as soon as possible.
Thanks.

Really appreciate for the reply.

Comment: for the comma and dot in the value are also disasters so I have to solve this problem too.

Comment: so if the commas are inside a string like `['17,61']` you don't want the mean of the two values, but the if list has multiple values, then you do want the mean?

Comment: @DerekO I've changed your solution to ''apply(lambda row: row[0] if len(row) == 1 else str(np.mean([float(p) for p in row])))" Because I removed all inappropriate commas and replaced them with dots, but a "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[' " came out when I try to run the program, doesn't the code ignore the '[' or ']' when running? How could I fix this error?

Comment: it's hard to tell where that error is coming from without being able to seeing your dataframe, but that means at some point in the code, `float('[')` is being executed. this could mean that there is a square bracket as a string inside one of the rows in your dataframe. there might be a row that looks like `['[']`

Comment: @DerekO I've found the problem, my df is readed form csv file, and I print the result it became ['16.51'] with the single quotations and if I print the df that create by pd.DataFrame() it became [16.5], how could I fix the csv file data?

Comment: glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do in fact want every comma and decimal to remain the same, then the final column must be of a string type because you can't have floats and strings together.

You could use `pd.apply` and convert the elements of any lists longer than 1 to floats, take the mean, and convert the result back to a string type. For example:

```
df['pricerange_All_new'] = df['pricerange_All'].apply(lambda row: row[0] if len(row) == 1 else str(np.mean([float(p.replace(',','.')) for p in row])))
```

Result:

```
df
     pricerange_All pricerange_All_new
0           [16.51]              16.51
1           [17,61]              17,61
2           [16,96]              16,96
3           [13,70]              13,70
4           [17,85]              17,85
5  [690.94, 690.76]             690.85
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a **dataframe** (df) that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'pricerange_All': [['16.51'], ['17,61'], ['16,96'], ['13,70'], ['17,85'], ['690.94', '690.76']]})

print(df)

----------------------------

     pricerange_All
0           [16.51]
1           [17,61]
2           [16,96]
3           [13,70]
4           [17,85]
5  [690.94, 690.76]
```

You could use a **lambda function** to apply the [mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function from the **statistics** package to each:

#### Code:

```
from statistics import mean 

df.pricerange_All = df.pricerange_All.apply(lambda x: mean(list(map(float, [item.replace(",", ".") for item in x]))))
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
   pricerange_All
0           16.51
1           17.61
2           16.96
3           13.70
4           17.85
5          690.85
```

#### Alternative (keep commas):

If you want to keep the commas, you could something like this instead:

```
df.pricerange_All = df.pricerange_All.apply(lambda x: mean(list(map(float, [item.replace(",", ".") for item in x]))) if len(x) > 1 else x[0])
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
  pricerange_All
0          16.51
1          17,61
2          16,96
3          13,70
4          17,85
5         690.85
```

Comment: i'm not sure if commas and dots in the strings remain the same as in the input. should `['17,61']` remain `['17,61']`?

Comment: ok - will look to update.

Comment: i'm not sure what OP wants, so you might consider adding on to what you already have

Comment: Thank you - yes - have updated with both options.